# Creating ECS cluster error: Unknown parameter in input: "tags", must be one of: clusterName

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to create an ecs cluster and attach tags to it and I see following error " Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "tags", must be one of: clusterName "

Am currently using 
boto3>=1.9.145
botocore>=1.12.145

```
   def createECSCluster(keyValueMap):
   ecsClient = boto3.client('ecs')
   response = ecsClient.create_cluster(                          
                 clusterName='ecscluster',
                 tags=[
                     {
                       'Key': 'XYZ',
                       'Value':'ABC'
                     }
                 ]  
               )
```

Error :

```
" Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "tags", must be one of: clusterName "
```

Comment: 'key' and 'value' should not start with capital letter.

Comment: that hasn't fixed the issue

Comment: You can try without tags argument and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me, using `key` and `value` (in lowercase):

```py
import boto3

ecsClient = boto3.client('ecs')
response = ecsClient.create_cluster(                          
                clusterName='ecscluster',
                tags=[
                    {
                    'key': 'XYZ',
                    'value':'ABC'
                    }
                ]  
            )
```

I am using boto3 1.9.104.

Comment: For some reason it's giving me the same error.I dont think its even going till the key or value I think the code breaks right at ``tags```